# Declarative Spring cache customization

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc, ehcache

I am using Spring Declarative Annotation based caching in my project .

applicationContext.xml

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
```

Currently, everything works perfectly using spring annotation based caching.
We use `ehCache` and `ConcurrentHashMap` based underline caching mechanism in development and local environment.

Now there is a requirement in project where I need to update the behavior of Spring cache framework with some specific business requirements.

I wonder if any one help me to figure it out how can I replace

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
```

this annotation with any spring class definition where I can customize the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Check out org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching.
Look at the comments in the source code.

It does the equivalent of the < cache:annotation-driven /> but in spring java config.

You will prolly need to override this class: org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect

Its responsible for wiring the advise in.

Answer (score 0):

This answer lead me in the right direction. The thing that I found about the inner workings of the caching support from spring is that its not Dependency injected outside of the cacheManager and KeyGenerator implementations. I wanted to subclass/extend the CacheAspectSupport and found that this class is first extended by CacheInterceptor but then that class is created using new statements in a class ProxyCachingConfiguration. To be able to replace the one class/method would take replacing a whole list of classes which doesn't sound very spring friendly (admittedly i could be missing something).

What i was expecting from the replacement of the line  was a fully listed out set of spring beans that composed all of the  AOP pointcuts, advice/aspects, etc. that make up the caching support, but it seems like this is alål just statically created classes with tight coupling between each other.